# How to do multi-day events in Solspace Calendar?

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

If I'm adding events for course that is run Wed 8-5, Thurs 8-5, and Fri 8-12, how would I do that? It's not technically a recurring event, I don't think, but at the same time, it's not individual instances either. This event (or course) runs multiple times a year, to complicate things a bit more.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to handle this would be to create 2 (or 3) separate events. The limitation here is the start and end times not being the same for all 3. If they were all the same, you could have done it as an individual event.

The first two are the same time, so those could be paired together, but the Friday one would have to be separate. :)

Comment: In the event I set the times to the same, for the sake of simplicity (though I'd like to request that as a feature :) ) would I do it as a repeating event?

Comment: You could do it as a repeating event if the times were all the same. You would basically have 2 options to do it:

1) Create event to start and end Wed, then repeat Daily every 1 days until Fri (if the event is happening on consecutive days).

2) Create event to start and end Wed, then repeat Weekly on Wed, Thurs, Friday, and set UNTIL date to be the last date (Friday).

The above sort of assume that you have a total of 3 occurrences, but the same advice in #2 would be required if this was happening on multiple weeks. :)

Comment: @Solspace Why isn't it posible to choose time as well with a repeated event? This is the only feature im missing. There will be a lot of content for each event, and not a good solution to reference to a seperate entry to reuse content.

Comment: @Spoeken this is because changing anything beyond a DATE repeat rule would drastically change the way Calendar handles event data. Currently, recurrences are handled by storing a simple RRULE code in the database which tells Calendar how many additional events to populate on the front end. Manipulating TIME requires a whole new database table that logs multiple variations of the same event, and while this is possible of course, it comes with many implications across the board. It's on our list for future consideration, however. But it is not a simple feature. :)

Comment: @Solspace I understand, thank you for your answer!

For others with the same problem: 
Because of our needs I went with the simpler Calendarize plugin, combined with an additional supertable with "extra" from and to hours only. Putting this in a seperate tab makes it organized for the editor, and querying on exact time is not a must for us so this should work out pretty well.